# JUnit 5 ConsoleLauncher doesn't work

Tags: java, junit, command-line, junit5

I have a DisplayNameDemo.java file as show below

**DisplayNameDemo.java**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@DisplayName("A special test case")
public class DisplayNameDemo {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Custom test name containing spaces")
    void testWithDisplayNameContainingSpaces() {
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("╯°□°）╯")
    void testWithDisplayNameContainingSpecialCharacters() {
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName(" ")
    void testWithDisplayNameContainingEmoji() {
    }
}
```

Then I compile it to the .class file use

```
javac -cp .:junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0.jar DisplayNameDemo.java
```

This command executed successfully，and I got a DisplayNameDemo.class file.

After that, I ran a command as show below

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0.jar --select-class DisplayNameDemo.class
```

But it failed and said that "org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: DisplayNameDemo.class"

[image: Error Info]

Please help me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the fully qualified class name with `--select-class`. In addition, it needs to be on the classpath. By default, it will only include classes that end with `Test` or `Tests`, so you'll have to use `--include-classname` to disable or change the filter.

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.1.0.jar \
     --classpath build/classes/java/test \
     --select-class example.DisplayNameDemo \
     --include-classname '.*'
```

Comment: And it's my fault that I didn't look carefully at the document, it has already stated what's "--include-classname" ' job, lol~